# Transforming text to rows using R or Excel with multiple columns

Tags: r, excel, transform

I have a **dataset** as mentioned below

```
CELL ID         VALUE 1 VALUE 2

54900, 41049    -111.55 -81.9   
13238, 14960     -89.4 -74.32   
56990, 41327     -106.99    -98.27  
56285, 6436      -68.87 -74.41  
17297,49055     -106.63 -95.84
```

I want to transform this data like this.

```
CELL ID VALUE 1 VALUE 2

54900 -111.55   -81.9   
41049 -111.55   -81.9   
13238 -89.4 -74.32

14960 -89.4 -74.32
```

... and so on ... I can use either excel or R

Comment: Ok, but is there a question here?  Paste a duplicate data set beneath, drag the second column of the duplicate set over to replace the first column, then delete the whole ColB and you're done.

Comment: With data.table, set `VALUE1 := NULL`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want something like the following:

```
df
      CELL_ID  VALUE1 VALUE2
1 54900,41049 -111.55 -81.90
2 13238,14960  -89.40 -74.32
3 56990,41327 -106.99 -98.27
4  56285,6436  -68.87 -74.41
5 17297,49055 -106.63 -95.84

ids <- strsplit(as.character(df$CELL_ID), split=',')

data.frame(CELL_ID = unlist(ids), VALUE1 = rep(df$VALUE1, sapply(ids, length)), VALUE2 = rep(df$VALUE2, sapply(ids, length)))    

   CELL_ID  VALUE1 VALUE2
1    54900 -111.55 -81.90
2    41049 -111.55 -81.90
3    13238  -89.40 -74.32
4    14960  -89.40 -74.32
5    56990 -106.99 -98.27
6    41327 -106.99 -98.27
7    56285  -68.87 -74.41
8     6436  -68.87 -74.41
9    17297 -106.63 -95.84
10   49055 -106.63 -95.84
```